# decode a json file that has a single unkeyed bool swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

there is a json file that returns 'true' or 'false' (Bool).
How can I parse it.
Json file doesn't have key. It returns only
true
or
false

Comment: Surely you can just read it and check its contents by hand? `if fileContents == "true" { ... }`

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: '''struct RegisteredModel:Codable{
    var registered:Bool
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        registered = try container.decode(Bool.self)
    }
}'''

Comment: '''let datatask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if (error == nil && data != nil){
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do{
let RegFeed = try decoder.decode(RegisteredModel.self, from: data!)
                    print(RegFeed.registered)
                    
                } catch{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        
        datatask.resume()'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONDecoder` is overkill for this purpose.

The `Data` representation of JSON `true` is

```
let data = Data([0x74, 0x72, 0x75, 0x65])
```

To check it simply create a `String` and compare with `"true"`

```
let isRegistered = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) == "true"
```

or compare the raw `Data` directly

```
let isRegistered = data == Data([0x74, 0x72, 0x75, 0x65])
```

Answer (score 1):

While I would almost certainly do this the way vadian suggests, JSONDecoder can definitely decode a top-level Bool:

```
let data = Data("true".utf8)
let value = try JSONDecoder().decode(Bool.self, from: data)
```

There's no need for a container. The (very slight) advantage of decoding this way is that it's much easier to make it tolerant of small differences like extra whitespace (for example a trailing newline). It's also easier to detect invalid data (for example, an empty result or an error) and distinguish it from `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You need `let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()`

```
struct RegisteredModel: Codable{
    var registered:Bool
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        registered = try container.decode(Bool.self)
    }
}

let json = "false"

let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(RegisteredModel.self, from: data)
    print(result)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```